# How to apply multiple filters to mapbox locations

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I've created a map for various buildings on a college campus and am trying to setup a navigational menu for the end user to select multiple filters to show only the applicable locations.

I've had success in creating each filter, however the filters don't communicate with each other. How do I call the value of each filter each time a filter is selected?

[Demo](https://offtherichterdesign.com/NDSU_reslife/)

HTML:

```
<div class="radio-toolbar">
  <p>Type</p>
  <input type="radio" id="Apartment_Type" name="type" onclick="Apartment_Type()">
  <label for="Apartment_Type">Apartment</label>


<input type="radio" id="Residence_Hall_Type" name="type" onclick="ResidenceHall_Type()">
  <label for="Residence_Hall_Type">Residence Hall</label>


  <input type="radio" id="Both_Type" name="type" onclick="Both_Type()" checked>
  <label for="Both_Type">Both</label>
  <br><br>
  <hr>
</div>

<div class="radio-toolbar">
  <p>Style <br> <span style="font-size: 10px;">(Residence Hall Only)</span></p>
  <input type="radio" id="Low_Rise_Style" name="style" onclick="Low_Rise_Style()">
  <label for="Low_Rise_Style">Traditional Style (Low Rise)</label>

  <br><br>

<input type="radio" id="High_Rise_Style" name="style" onclick="High_Rise_Style()">
  <label for="High_Rise_Style">Suite Style (High Rise)</label>
  <br><br>


<input type="radio" id="Apartment_Style" name="style" onclick="Apartment_Style()">
  <label for="Apartment_Style">Apartment Style</label>

<input type="radio" id="All_Style" name="style" onclick="All_Style()" checked>
  <label for="All_Style">All</label>
  <br><br>
  <hr>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
map.on('load', function Apartment_Type() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox_apartmenttype = document.getElementById("Apartment_Type");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox_apartmenttype.checked == true){
    map.setFilter('Locations', ['==', ['get', 'type'], 'apartment']);
  } else {
  }
});

map.on('load', function ResidenceHall_Type() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox_halltype = document.getElementById("Residence_Hall_Type");


  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox_halltype.checked == true){
    map.setFilter('Locations', ['==', ['get', 'type'], 'hall']);


  } else {

  }
});

map.on('load', function Both_Type() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox_bothtype = document.getElementById("Both_Type");


  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox_bothtype.checked == true){
    var bothtype=[
        "all",
        ["in", "type", 'apartment','hall'],
    ]
    map.setFilter('Locations',bothtype)
  } else {
  }
});

map.on('load', function Low_Rise_Style() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox_lowrisestyle = document.getElementById("Low_Rise_Style");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox_lowrisestyle.checked == true){
    map.setFilter('Locations', ['==', ['get', 'style'], 'low rise']);
  } else {
  }
});

map.on('load', function High_Rise_Style() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox_highrisestyle = document.getElementById("High_Rise_Style");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox_highrisestyle.checked == true){
    map.setFilter('Locations', ['==', ['get', 'style'], 'high rise']);
  } else {
  }
});

map.on('load', function Apartment_Style() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox_apartmentstyle = document.getElementById("Apartment_Style");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox_apartmentstyle.checked == true){
    map.setFilter('Locations', ['==', ['get', 'style'], 'apartment']);
  } else {
  }
});

map.on('load', function All_Style() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox_allstyle = document.getElementById("All_Style");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox_allstyle.checked == true){
    var allstyle=[
        "all",
        ["in", "style", 'high rise','low rise','apartment'],
    ]
    map.setFilter('Locations',allstyle)
  } else {
  }
});
```

Comment: If your filters are over the same single source, what I would do is to assign to all of them the same event handler, composing the filter with the options selected and then launch a single query. 
As your filters aren’t dynamic but static and a limited number, it should work

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts @jscastro. That makes sense, however, I'm unsure how to write it. I've edited my post to include the some of the HMTL and JavaScript for the filters. Could you show me a quick sample of how I could write out what you are suggesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working!
HTML:

```
<div class="radio-toolbar">
  <p>Type</p>
  <input type="radio" id="Apartment_Type" name="type" value="apartment" onclick="ApplyFilters()">
  <label for="Apartment_Type">Apartment</label>


<input type="radio" id="Residence_Hall_Type" name="type" value="hall" onclick="ApplyFilters()">
  <label for="Residence_Hall_Type">Residence Hall</label>


  <input type="radio" id="Both_Type" name="type" value="both" onclick="ApplyFilters()" checked>
  <label for="Both_Type">Both</label>
  <br><br>
  <hr>
</div>

<div class="radio-toolbar">
  <p>Style <br> <span style="font-size: 10px;">(Residence Hall Only)</span></p>
  <input type="radio" id="Low_Rise_Style" name="style" value="low rise" onclick="ApplyFilters()">
  <label for="Low_Rise_Style">Traditional Style (Low Rise)</label>

  <br><br>

<input type="radio" id="High_Rise_Style" name="style" value="high rise" onclick="ApplyFilters()">
  <label for="High_Rise_Style">Suite Style (High Rise)</label>
  <br><br>

<input type="radio" id="Apartment_Style" name="style" value="apartment" onclick="ApplyFilters()">
  <label for="Apartment_Style">Apartment Style</label>

<input type="radio" id="All_Style" name="style" value="all" onclick="ApplyFilters()" checked>
  <label for="All_Style">All</label>
  <br><br>
  <hr>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function ApplyFilters() {
 
        
var type = document.querySelector("input[type=radio][name=type]:checked").value;

if (type === 'both'){
var filtertype = ["in", "type", 'hall','apartment'];
}else{
var filtertype = ["in", "type", type];
}

var style = document.querySelector("input[type=radio][name=style]:checked").value;

if (style === 'all'){
var filterstyle = ["in", "style", 'low rise','high rise','apartment',''];
}else{
var filterstyle = ["in", "style", style];
}

var filters=[
      "all",
      filtertype,
      filterstyle,      
  ]
  map.setFilter('Locations',filters)
  
};
```

Comment: Great to see you followed the approach of creating a single event handles and add the clauses there! Congrats